# What are the consequences in dying as a Hardcore?

Tags: diablo-iii

Dying as a Hardcore in Diablo 2 looks different, in comparison with dying as a Hardcore, in Diablo 3.

Can someone provide the principal consequences in dying as a Hardcore in Diablo 3?

**extra**: Can I delete, from my heroes list, my hardcore hero? or must I keep him there for some reason?

Comment: Please, don't down vote without a good reason (just for fun). Leave a comment, if you are hunting medals, wait, you'll get plenty of time to down vote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hardcore is actually [very similar to Diablo II](http://www.gamespot.com/features/if-youre-not-playing-diablo-iii-hardcore-youre-doing-it-wrong-6376560/), there are a few differences but dying isn't one of them.  Death is still permanent.

**The main differences are:**

- Hardcore characters do not have access to the cash-money auction house.  This is believed by most to an effort to limit the economic chaos that will result from folks botting the game to get money in the "softcore" mode.
- You have to reach level 10 with a regular character, before you can start a hardcore 
  character.
- Dead Hardcore characters above level 10 can be "archived" to the "Hall of Fallen Heroes", where you can see a few stats about them.  This action also removes them from the slots of your character selection screen.

The [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yV2omBTCGQ) below does a good job of summarizing most of the effects of death as a hardcore character in Diablo III.

**Behaviors returning from Diablo II**

- Hardcore players [can only team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_III#Hardcore_mode) with other Hardcore players.
- Your ghost is still able to chat after you die, but you will not ever be able to play the character again.
- Hardcore characters have a red title that is unique from Softcore players

Comment: and about the loot? my gear, it can be picked up by a friend or something like this?

Comment: I'm taking this as correct answer. BUT please, take a look at [@Oak's answer as well](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66379/12936) because there more information there.

Comment: What exactly does "archiving" a dead hero do?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon check about 3:10 in the video, it shows you.  Basically it opens up the slot for another new hero, and saves the old hero for you to look at and reminisce about.  Some stats for the dead hero are also displayed.

Answer (score 6):

When your hardcore hero dies, you can no longer play with that hero, and **you lose all the items the hero was carrying at the time of death**, even if you play with friends (your corpse cannot be looted).

As far as I know, you do not lose anything which is shared - so you do not lose items stored in your chest, or artisan progress, or gold, etc.

A dead hardcore hero does not occupy a hero slot (after you remove them, as per [Ebongo's excellent answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66378/122)).

Comment: So my chest is shared between my account. Independent if is a hardcore or a softcore will be the same chest?

Comment: @MichelAyres you cannot share items between HC and non-HC characters in any way. Specifically, the chest is not shared, there's a separate HC and non-HC chest. My point was that you do not lose items stored in your HC chest when a HC hero dies.

Comment: Ok, and what about the gold? is it shared like the chest? (Sorry for being so boring about it, just trying to cover more the answer for future references)

Comment: @MichelAyres haven't checked, but as far as I know you don't lose anything which is shared; updated my answer to include that information.