# Do hardcore Artisans maintain there level if my hardcore character dies?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the consequences in dying as a Hardcore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66359/what-are-the-consequences-in-dying-as-a-hardcore)

After reading  [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66499/does-the-artisans-level-carry-through-to-higher-acts)  I was wondering if you only had 1 hardcore character and took the time to spend on the Artisan's levels, would those levels remain even after that hardcore character died? (IE: if you only had 1 hardcore character and they died, would those Artisans levels remain after creating a new one?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [Hardcore Artisans are account wide, not per-character.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66503/336)

Comment: Thanks! The other question did not specify if they maintained their level if you only had 1 hardcore character. So I just wanted to clarify that.